# Intel XDK - codesign - no identity found - AdHoc - Distribution Profile

Tags: ios, cordova, build, adhoc, intel-xdk

I'am developing an Hybrid mobile APP using Cordova in Intel XDK.

While developing, Emulating & Testing and also Building Development Builds to test on real device, all worked well.

Now I created an Production Certificate and an Distribution Provisioning Profile, and let the Intel XDK Build the APP for Ad Hoc to send it via "Application Loader" to the App store to roll it out on multiple Test-Devices.

But here the online-build stops saying "[no identity found](http://pastebin.com/dN3BvM39)" see the pastebin.

What do I do wrong??

Answer (score 2):

Ok Folks, it worked that way:

1. DO NOT NAME YOUR Wildcard APP ID like your final APP ID (it CONFUSES a lot) -.-
2. Download the CSR from the XDK
3. Create an Production Certificate for "App Store and Ad Hoc" with that CSR
4. Download that Certificate and upload it to the iOS Build in the XDK
5. Create an Distribution Provisioning Profile BE AWARE OF MAKING MISTAKES NOW
6. Chose "Distribution > Ad Hoc", then "next"
7. Choose THE RIGHT!!!!! App ID (not the Wildcard, like I did, because it was named like the right App ID, my Fault) then "Continue"
8. Choose THE RIGHT!!!! Certificate (generated with the CSR from the XDK, not -like I did- generated with an local MAC keychain)
9. Download the Porovisioning Profile and set it in the Build-Settings
10. Build your APP

It is my FIRST APP so all that Settings (Certificates, Devices, Provisioning Profiles, ...) are really confusing for me because I don't now their relation ^^

May that also helps someone else who is confused like I was -.-